# Normalize a Data frame in Python excluding nan

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, na

I want to subtract each row in a Pandas Data frame with the mean of that row (for normalization). Now, the issue is that there are some nan values in the Data frame. I don't want to use them (nan values) in calculating mean , and I don't want the nan values to be subtracted either.

For example, a row of Data frame is like this

```
Row : NaN 5 6 NaN 3 2
```

I want to be like this:

```
Row : NaN 1 2 NaN -1 -2
```

The code I'm using right now is this: Assume data is my Data Frame

```
    data.sub(data.mean(axis=1,skipna=True), axis=0)
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps: `data.sub(data.mean(axis=1,skipna=True), axis=1)` ?

Comment: @NickilMaveli `axis=0` in the call to `sub`... I believe

Comment: @piRSquared: Ah, Got that. You were right.